# .NET OracleClient query returning incorrect fewer results than expected

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, system.data.oracleclient

I am using the .NET OracleClient (in C#) and I have a query returning incorrect (fewer rows)  results than expected.

This is the only time I have ever seen this happen.

I can cut/paste the query into SQl Developer or sql*plus and it returns the correct 281 rows.
When it runs in the .NET app, the datatable has only 280 (and I know which record is missing).

Has anyone ever seen this happen or have any ideas on why?

Here is the C# code

```
string llQuery = "select DISTINCT " +
                 "case when aliased_item = 'TIME SERIES' then 'TS_ALIAS' else 'TIME_SERIES' end data_type, " +
                 "cwms_ts_id " +
                 "from (select aliased_item, SUBSTR(cwms_ts_id, instr(cwms_ts_id, '.') + 1, LENGTH(cwms_ts_id) - instr(cwms_ts_id, '.')) cwms_ts_id " +
                 "from CWMS_V_TS_ID2) " +                             
                 "union all " +
                 "select DISTINCT 'LOCATION_LEVEL' data_type, cwms_ts_id " +
                 "from (select SUBSTR(location_level_id, instr(location_level_id, '.') + 1, LENGTH(location_level_id) - instr(location_level_id, '.')) cwms_ts_id " +
                 "from CWMS_V_LOCATION_LEVEL) " +                             
                 " order by data_type desc, cwms_ts_id";                             
try
{
    OracleConnection connection_obj = new OracleConnection();
    connection_obj.ConnectionString = connStr;
    connection_obj.Open();

    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection_obj;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = llQuery;

        DataTable dtLvl = new DataTable();
        dtLvl.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
```

and here is the query, which is copied/pasted and the characters ",+ removed etc.

```
select DISTINCT 
case when aliased_item = 'TIME SERIES' then 'TS_ALIAS' else 'TIME_SERIES' end      data_type, 
cwms_ts_id 
from (select aliased_item, SUBSTR(cwms_ts_id, instr(cwms_ts_id, '.') + 1, LENGTH(cwms_ts_id) - instr(cwms_ts_id, '.')) cwms_ts_id 
from CWMS_V_TS_ID2)
union all 
select DISTINCT 'LOCATION_LEVEL' data_type, cwms_ts_id 
from (select SUBSTR(location_level_id, instr(location_level_id, '.') + 1, LENGTH(location_level_id) - instr(location_level_id, '.')) cwms_ts_id 
from CWMS_V_LOCATION_LEVEL)
```

the missing record happens to be

```
data_type   cwms_ts_id
=========   ========================================
TS_ALIAS    Code-ProjectStatus.Const.1Day.1Day.ALIAS
```

After the query executes in the app, 
dtLvl.Rows.Count = 280 not 281, 
and the above indicated record is not there.

At a loss for where to look next for why this might be happening - as I mentioned I've never seen it happen before

thanks for any ideas !

Comment: Try using verbatim string and copy your working query there like ` `string query = @"select DISTINCT 
case when aliased_item = 'TIME SERIES' then 'TS_ALIAS' else 'TIME_SERIES' end      data_type, 
cwms_ts_id 
from (select aliased_item, SUBSTR(cwms_ts_id, instr(cwms_ts_id, '.') + 1, LENGTH(cwms_ts_id) - instr(cwms_ts_id, '.')) cwms_ts_id 
from CWMS_V_TS_ID2)
union all 
select DISTINCT 'LOCATION_LEVEL' data_type, cwms_ts_id 
from (select SUBSTR(location_level_id, instr(location_level_id, '.') + 1, LENGTH(location_level_id) - instr(location_level_id, '.')) cwms_ts_id 
from CWMS_V_LOCATION_LEVEL)"

Comment: per your suggestion I did with same result. I added a second string variable and assigned the copied/pasted string with llquery2=@"..."  and then verified   with boolean test = (llquery = llquery2)

Comment: I changed the query to just return the missing row, and still no record, though I get one row running it againt the db using sql dev/sql*plus, etc

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the field ALIASED_ITEM.  for instance this query "select * from CWMS_V_TS_ID2 where aliased_item is not null" returns 3000ish rows in sql, and 0 in the app. If i remove the "where aliased_item is not null" it runs fine. It seems to be having an issue when aliased_item is not null.   so very confused

Comment: I found a workaround, that soes not explain why OracleClient not working but illustrates the issue. if I create a view like so "create or replace view rdl_ts_aliases as
select * from CWMS_V_TS_ID2 where aliased_item = 'TIME SERIES'" - it works in the app fine using that view. but the same query fails in the app. no clue

Comment: This isn't really an answer to my question, but changing providers from System.Data.OracleClient  to the ODP.NET managed client works. the query returns the correct data.